# Is "'em" short for 'him', 'them' or both?

Tags: apostrophe

I know that the apostrophe can be used to denote the omission of letters in a word, so I'm wondering then if *'em* can be used to denote the colloquial shorthand for *him*, or if it would be more proper to use *'im* (and that *'em* is really just shorthand for *them*).

Comment: In AmE, 'em is *them*. I myself haven't ever seen *'im* written for AmE, but it is sometimes said when following a word ending in certain consonants, especially *g*, e.g. *hang 'im*. But we might only be imitating John Wayne here.

Comment: In speech, it's very difficult to tell the difference between *'em* and *'im*. But there's no reason not to preserve the distinction in writing.

Comment: Steve McGarrett always pronounced his end-of-episode instructions on _Hawaii Five-O_ identically. One suspect caught dead to rights: "Book'm Danno—murder one." Multiple suspects caught dead to rights: "Book'm, Danno—murder one." But I have no doubt that that so punctilious an investigator would have kept his written instructions exact and distinct—either "book 'im" or "book 'em," as their numbers dictated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have only read or heard *'em* used for *them*, though there is some disagreement in the comments (the discrepancy may be due to *'im* and *'em* sounding quite similar in speech).

You are correct that *'im* can be used for *him*, and if you insist on butchering the language even further, you can use *'er* for *her*.

However, keep in mind that these abbreviations typically aren't used in written language. The only case they should be used is when you want to emphasize the fact that an accent is being used. For instance, in Mark Twain's novels which take place in the South, those abbreviations are used when people are speaking, but are not used narratively.

In this example, the excerpt from the book *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer* is **spoken**, helping to emphasize the fact that Tom is speaking with the drawl and colloquialisms of Southern America:

> “She! She never licks anybody – whacks **’em** over the head with her thimble – and who cares for that, I’d like to know...”

While the narrative parts of the story do not use such colloquialisms:

> The old lady pulled her spectacles down and looked over **them** about the room; then she put them up and looked out under them.

And for reference, a quote from the sequel, *Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, abbreviating **him**:

> “Yes, Mars Sid, A dog. Cur'us dog, too. Does you want to go en look at **’im**?”

*Thank you to [**bib**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/23491/bib) for providing the quotes.*

Comment: It's called "eye dialect". And there is no standard, so _'em_ is as common with singular as with plural, just as _'d_ is as common with _had_ as _would_, or _'s_ is as common with _has_ as _is_. They're totally indistinguishable in speech (not just "illiterate" speech) and therefore, if spelling rules are relaxt, there is no reason not to spell'em as you see'em, and tell'em I said so.

Comment: @JohnLawler: This question seems to be about written English, not speech.

Comment: @IQAndreas *Tom Sawyer* - "She! She never licks anybody—whacks 'em over the head with her thimble ..."  No examples of *'im* in that work.

Comment: @IQAndreas In *Huckleberry Finn* - "Yes, Mars Sid, A dog.  Cur'us dog, too.  Does you want to go en look at 'im?"

Comment: @JohnLawler Good advice, although I confess that every time I’ve tried your final *ipse dixit* on folks, they’ve looked at me like I was a crazy man. :)

Comment: @bib - Thank you so much for tracking down that information! I added the quotes to the answer.

Comment: Why try to imitate actual pronunciation with English spelling? That's like trying to paint a picture with a burnt log. Eye dialect is generally used to put down people's speech (why spell it wrong if it isn't the wrong way to talk?), and is frequently quite offensive, especially to minorities. It's best avoided. If you really want to represent speech using letters, use an [English Phonemic Alphabet](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), or, for fine details, the IPA.

Comment: @JohnLawler Fact of life: most people have accents; I don't see it as offensive acknowledging that. And if you are a good writer (and providing the accent doesn't detract from the story), fictional characters are likely to have accents too.

Comment: @JohnLawler When writing a for character, you can either **(1)** explain at the beginning "The character here speaks in a southern drawl", **(2)** let the reader choose to imagine the character with any accent they want, or **(3)** write in such a way that reading the dialogs will "automatically" give the right accent, no explanations needed.

Comment: @John « _'em_ is as common with singular as with plural » — Not in my experience it ain’t. I’ve seen _’em_ used to mean ‘them’ hundreds of times, and I’ve seen _’im_ used to mean ‘him’ hundreds of times. I don’t recall **ever** seeing the reverse. The main reason for this, I would guess, is that they are **not** indistinguishable in speech. Reduced _them_ is /əm/, while reduced _him_ is /ɪm/ in many (most?) dialects. They can be reduced further and coalesce, but they frequently don’t.

Answer (score 0):

Them.  But don't forget that colloquial English uses "they" or "them" in place of one, to avoid sounding formal while avoiding specific genders.